# AWS CloudFormation : Find Lambda Alias using partial text and delete those alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a Lambda which is having many versions and alias created for each version. Here is san example

- Apple_Version_1
- Apple_Version_1.1
- Apple_Version_1.2
- Apple_Version_1.2.1
- Apple_Version_1.2.2
- Apple_Version_1.3
- Apple_Version_1.3.1

Now, i have a partial text, say "**Apple_Version_1.2.**", so with this, find out all the Versions that are starting with that text and be able to delete using cloud formation.

So in this case, need to get below

- Apple_Version_1.2.1
- Apple_Version_1.2.2

Thanks in advance

amazon-web-services
amaz

Comment: Find using what? Python? AWS CLI?

Comment: using cloudformation stack, not with the CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't do this in plain CloudFormation (CFN), as CFN is not a programming language and has very limited capabilities.

The long answer: you could design your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html) to use in your CFN template. The resource would be in the form of **lambda function** which would process and return the aliases to your stack for further use.